# ModuleNotFound error after successful installation of package

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I installed pandas on a remote server (without sudo permissions) using `pip3 install --user pandas`.

The installation was successful:

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.21.6 pandas-1.1.5 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2022.1 six-1.16.0
```

I also verified my python version:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.0
```

However, I still get module not found error when I execute my python file.

Traceback:

```
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I attempted to add the following to my python script but am still getting an error:

```
import sys,os
BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, BASE)
```

Comment: Virtual env, such as `venv`, will mask/ignore global packages.

Comment: use `python3 -m pip install <package name>`

Comment: Are  you running your Python file from a command line, or inside an IDE?  Many Python IDEs have their own independent Python installations.